# Convert Ansible variable to integer for arithmetic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, jinja2

I would like to execute a command to obtain the current AWS EC2 launch template version in an integer format so I can do basic arithmetic on it to use in subsequent queries / deletes.

For example:

```
    tasks:
  - name: Lookup current default version of EC2 launch template
    command: aws ec2 describe-launch-template-versions --launch-template-id lt-xxx --filters Name=is-default-version,Value=true --query 'LaunchTemplateVersions[*].[VersionNumber]'
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: result

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      msg: '{{ result.stdout }}'
    delegate_to: localhost
```

If this output is '5' I would like to subtract 1 from it so I can execute an additional command to do the following:

```
aws ec2 delete-launch-template-versions --launch-template-id lt-xxx --versions {{result - 1}}
```

I realize this will not work as written, but this is the premise I'm going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to an integer. For example

```yaml
    - command: echo 5
      register: result
    - command: "echo {{ result.stdout|int - 1 }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
  result.stdout: '4'
```

The type of the [*command*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-builtin-command-module-execute-commands-on-targets) return values' attribute [*stdout*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#return-stdout) is string. See the results below

```yaml
    - command: echo 5
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          result.stdout: {{ result.stdout }}
          result.stdout|type_debug: {{ result.stdout|type_debug }}
          result.stdout|int|type_debug: {{ result.stdout|int|type_debug }}
```

```yaml
  msg: |-
    result.stdout: 5
    result.stdout|type_debug: AnsibleUnsafeText
    result.stdout|int|type_debug: int
```